# How can I use sub-directory?

Tags: laravel

I am new and install Laravel 6.x. And then I got a welcome(default) page.
But I didn't use the sub-directory in the website URL
I created the sub-directory like this below.

"www.test.com/test"

But that is not working.

**/routes/web.php** code source

1. It is working well.

> ```
> Route::get('/', function () {
>      return view('./posts/test');
> });
> ```

[image]

2. It is not working. So I got the "404" page.

> ```
> Route::get('/test', function () {
>      return view('./posts/test');
> });
> ```

[image]

How can I use sub-directory?

Comment: what you are getting now and what is the expected result?

Comment: What is your default page URL?

Comment: Please see again the text, thanks !

Comment: I solved the problem.   the problem was apache conf   <Directory "/home/....../public"> AllowOverride all </Directory>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Apache configuration:

```
<Directory "/home/....../public">
    AllowOverride all 
</Directory>
```

*(posted as a community wiki-answer because this question has been answered in the comments)*